# What does Tensorflow's CyclicalLearningRate scale_fn argument mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

In the documentation for tensorflow's [`CyclicalLearningRate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/CyclicalLearningRate), there is an argument called `scale_fn`.

According to the documentation, `scale_fn` is

> A function. Scheduling function applied in cycle

However this explanation isn't very clear.
What argument does this function take and what should it output?
More specifically, how does one use this?
It's required for using the `CyclicalLearningRate` but I couldn't find a comprehensive explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/CyclicalLearningRate) is not very enlightening in its usage. A better explanation along with an example can be found in [Super Convergence with Cyclical Learning Rates in TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/super-convergence-with-cyclical-learning-rates-in-tensorflow-c1932b858252); quoting:

> ```
> from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import CyclicalLearningRate
>
> cyclical_learning_rate = CyclicalLearningRate( 
>   initial_learning_rate=3e-7,  maximal_learning_rate=3e-5, 
>   step_size=2360,  scale_fn=lambda x: 1 / (2.0 ** (x - 1)), 
>   scale_mode='cycle')
> ```
>
> **Scale function**
>
> The Scale function is the function controlling the change from the
> initial learning rate to the maximal learning rate and back to the
> initial learning rate. In [Smith's] paper this is one of triangular,
> triangular 2 or exponential range. In my own experiments with models
> for generative images (for example super resolution) I have found
> Triangular 2 to be most effective.
>
> **Triangular**: A basic triangular cycle with no amplitude scaling:
>
> ```
> lambda x: 1.0
> ```
>
> **Triangular 2**: A basic triangular cycle that scales initial amplitude
> by half with each cycle:
>
> ```
> lambda x: 1 / (2.0 ** (x — 1))
> ```
>
> **Exponential range**: A cycle that scales initial amplitude by gamma to
> the power of the cycle iterations with each cycle:
>
> ```
> lambda x: gamma ** x
> ```

And FWIW, the author also notes:

> I believe that maybe a lack of clarity on these parameters is one of the reasons this TensorFlow learning rate schedule is not in wider use.